# Crypto Comare API response data type

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

I am making a call to Crypto Compares API to get all of the tickers along with their data (https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/). I am having difficulty finding what the data type is of the returned json. I am able to turn it into a [String: Any], but the value looks like it also contains two dictionaries. Here is my code where I try to cast the json object into the dictionary.

```
guard let responseDictionary = responseObject as? [String: Any] else {
 print("WRONG")
 return
}
```

The code above successfully works, but I am not able to access the rest of the dictionary. I have also tried [String: [String: Any]] and most variations of it. Just for reference.. I am trying to access the coin name in the return.

***UPDATE: For anyone interested I had to save the responseDictionary["Data"] as! [String: [String: String]] then I could access the rest of the data as a dictionary, however when casting the responseObject it would only let me use [String: Any] instead of [String: [String: Any]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since you are not sure about the format of the dictionary, use `dump` to print it out beautifully. Then you can figure out a propert way of casting using `guard let`

Try this out

```
dump(responseObject)
```